# Different Moq, or the same?

Tags: .net, moq, moqcontrib

So I found these 2 Moq library with the same name. [*Moq:an enjoyable mocking library*](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MOQ) and this one [*Moq:The simplest mocking library for .NET and Silverlight*](https://code.google.com/p/moq/) Are they the same? I am thinking no. If they are different which one is better, in terms of usability? Btw if this question is not meant to SO, please tell me adn I will post it at the appropriate place. Please do not down vote I want my point :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they're the same.

The first link is the NuGet Package page.
The second link is the project page on Google Code.

Comment: Interesting, because when I went to manage my nuget package I see that there is two so I was like okayyyyy.

Comment: I see only one package on my manager. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Moq.Contrib is a different project. It gathers community extensions to Moq (mainly auto mocking containers). Notice it has a dependency on the actual Moq package.

Comment: Stupid icon threw me off